# debugging in codelite - "GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted"

Tags: gdb

while debugging in codelite this error appears in the terminal :

[image]

could anyone help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [codelite github](https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/1587)

1. > This error message is harmless and can be ignored. If the terminal
   >   does not "pause" when your code terminates, you can enable this from
   >   Project Settings->General->Pause when execution ends
2. > To configure different temrinal, you do it from Ubuntu's terminal,
   >   like this:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
   > ```

Comment: Doesn't work.  None of the other terminals work to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Found a potential work around:

https://rr-project.org/

A reversible debugger, and a drop-in replacement for gdb.  Perhaps upon installation it won't have the same crap .gdbinit mechanism.  I tried the above fixes and all fixes in other related threads to this problem and they don't work.  It's obviously time to upgrade my debugging softare.

I will post back here if it works / doesn't work to fix this particular error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted" in a Virtual Box share.

Move your files in a tmp folder **outside** the shared directory:

```
[user@localhost tmp]$ sudo cp -r /home/share/* .
```